# error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with error CS0236.

```
public class Converter
{
    public string Celsiusz { get; set; }
    public string Fahrenheit { get; set; }
    public string Kelvin{ get; set; }
    public string Rankinen { get; set; }
    public string Reaumur { get; set; }
    public string Romer { get; set; }
    public string Delisle { get; set; }
    public string Newton { get; set; }


    double CelsiuszDouble;

    bool bupa = double.TryParse(Newton, out CelsiuszDouble); 
 }
```

Are coming two errors:

First:

> error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static
>   field, method, or property  Converter.Newton

Second:

> error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static
>   field, method, or property Converter.CelsiuszDouble

Comment: In the error `Converter.Nevton` isn't that a spelling mistake in your code in that case?

Comment: That last line of code doesn't make sense in the class definition.  I suspect it should be in a method somewhere.  (Both of the last lines of code, actually.)

Comment: sorry  the errors was written in may language and I translated to english with mistake.  I fixed already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @David You cant write such a code in class definition . You must write that part **bool=....** inside either **Constructor** or a **Method**.

Answer (score 1):

This code is trying to access the public property of a non-static class, therefore you have no instance of it to access.

```
 bool bupa = double.TryParse(Newton, out CelsiuszDouble);
```

If you change the property to have a private backing field, you could use that in your code.